# c# Insert/Update multiple lookup values to an SPListItem

Tags: sharepoint, splistitem, spfieldcollection

sharepoint allows multiple items to be added for a lookup column type. Is there a good article that has the code snippet to update or add lookup values?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this object SPFieldLookupValueCollection. What you need to do is to create an instance of this class, fill the collection with SPFieldLookupValue objects and assign the collection to the field, that's it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/02c889fc-6b15-4a60-b0f6-ed5d020ec6c2

Comment: Thanks Vladi Gubler but that example is not as complete as your answer (code wise). Any other solid link on how to populate multilookup field or update (adding additional values in addition to what is alread in that field).